# Subtraction of two column in views

Tags: views

How to subtracts two column in view?
for example:
 say column A and Column B need to subtract i,e `[column A - column B]= column C`.How can I achieve this is there any module available for it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add another field, select `Math Expression` from `Global` group, then in there put something like `[field_1_total] 2 [field_2_total]`

there is not need any addition module

Comment: i am using view aggregation for one column is field from content type another column is a count getting using aggregation module in simple words one column is not field which is there in content type its a custom field added now i want difference of column1 -column2

Comment: is it [field_1_total] 2 [field_2_total] or [field_1_total] - [field_2_total] ....?

Comment: @though field tokens are listing and i am giving something  [field_total] - [title_1] its showing only first column result....not substracting

Comment: @Vicky8888: i am subtracting tokens but its not considering its retaining the first column result....its not substracting

Comment: go to view ->add Global:math expression from the list of available fields->then go expression textfield of Global:math expression->put there [field_total] - [title_1]

Comment: @Vicky8888: I did this only please check the screen shot

Comment: where is screen shot?

Comment: question i have edited now...i have added there screen shot check

Comment: once check fields u r subtracting are of same type (eg:textfield)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31692/discussion-between-neethu-and-vicky8888).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc).

Comment: i think it allows to SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG selected columns in Views.

Comment: No, this is not good solution, he can achieve it with `Global:math expression` field

Comment: I think this only does math operations for rows and not columns.